# Covert excel to json using python

Tags: python, json, excel, xlrd

I am a rookie programmer and new to the community. I am trying to read data from an Excel file and convert the contents of the file into a JSON format. I know there have been questions about this sort of thing in the past on StackOverflow - with the help of these questions I was able to come up with a solution but it doesn't work as expected.

This what the excel file looks like:

[image]

This is what the JSON is SUPPOSED to look like:

```
{"linesOfFruits": [
    {
        "title" : {
            "en": "Apple"
        },
        "url" : "https://isThisApple/123123"
    },
    {
        "title" : {
            "en": "Banana"
        },
        "teams" : [
            {
                "title" : {
                    "en": "Red Banana"
                },
                "url" : "https://isThisBanana/123124"
            },
            {
                "title" : {
                    "en": "Green Banana"
                },
                "url" : "https://isThisBanana/123125"
            },
            {
                "title" : {
                    "en": "Yellow Banana"
                },
                "url" : "https://isThisBanana/123126"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "title" : {
            "en": "Grape"
        },
        "teams" : [
            {
                "title" : {
                    "en": "Orange Grape"
                },
                "url" : "https:/isThisGrape/1234"
            },
            {
                "title" : {
                    "en": "Blue Grape"
                },
                "url" : "https:/isThisGrape/1235"
            },
            {
                "title" : {
                    "en": "Pink Grape"
                },
                "url" : "https:/isThisGrape/1236"
            },
        ]
    }



]}
```

However this is what my code prints out:

```
{"linesOfBusiness":
    [
        {
            "title": "Apple",
            "url": "https://isThisApple/123123"

        },
        {
            "title": "Banana",
            "teams": ["Orange Grape", "Blue Grape", "Pink Grape"],
            "url": "https://isThisBanana/123124"

        },
        {
            "title": "Grape",
            "teams": ["Orange Grape", "Blue Grape", "Pink Grape"],
            "url": "https:/isThisGrape/1234"}
    ]

}
```

Also note that if the teams field is (All) then the teams array can be omitted in the JSON

This is what I have so far:

```py
import json
import sys

import xlrd


def convertToJson(excelFile, sheetName, jsonFile):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excelFile)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheetName)

    data = []
    keys = ['title', 'teams', 'url']
    teams = []

    for row_number in range(worksheet.nrows):
        if row_number == 0:
            continue
        row_data = {}
        empty = False

        team = {}
        list = worksheet.row(0)

        for col_number, cell in enumerate(worksheet.row(row_number)):

            if col_number == 0 and cell.value == '':
                empty = True
            elif col_number == 0:
                empty = False
                teams.clear()

            if col_number == 1 and ( empty is True or cell.value != '(All)'):
                team[keys[0]] = worksheet.row(row_number)

                teams.append(cell.value)
                print(teams)
            elif col_number == 1 and cell.value == '(All)':
                continue

            # skip the number of fruits since it does not have to be in JSON file
            if (col_number == 3):
                continue

            if col_number == 1:
                if teams.__len__() > 0:
                    row_data[keys[col_number]] = teams
            elif col_number == 0 and cell.value == '':
                continue
            else:
                row_data[keys[col_number]] = cell.value

        if 'title' in row_data:
            data.append(row_data)

    with open(jsonFile, 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(json.dumps({
            'linesOfBusiness': data
        }))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Have been stuck on this for some time :)

Comment: Have you tried using pandas? Pandas can read and write both excel and json files.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! No I have not because it needs to be a python script.

Comment: Pandas is a python package. It makes handling tabular data much easier. You can use it in a python script. It might even be as simple as ```df=pandas.read_excel('file.xlsx')``` followed by ```df.to_json('file.json')``` I highly recommend pandas for handling excel files.

Comment: Oh wow. Sorry I didn't know about Pandas. I will try that for sure and let you know!! Thank you!

Comment: @iamchoosinganame I tried it with pandas. It converts it to json but definitely not in the format that I want it in

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative solution:

```
import requests
import xlrd


class ExcelParser:

  @staticmethod
  def parse_cell(cell, datemode):
      # TODO Extend to all Excel date types
      if cell.ctype == 0:
          return ""
      elif cell.ctype == 1:
          return str(cell.value)
      elif cell.ctype == 3:
          datetime = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(cell.value, datemode)
          return datetime
      else:
          return cell.value

  @staticmethod
  def from_url(url):
      response = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
      if response.status_code != 200:
          raise Exception("Excel couldn't be downloaded. Http status: {status}".format(status=response.status_code))

      xls_raw_data = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=response.content)
      # Use xlrd.open_workbook(filename=<path>) to load content from file

      sheet = xls_raw_data.sheet_by_index(0)
      title, header, *rows = [[ExcelParser.parse_cell(cell, xls_raw_data.datemode) for cell in row] for row in sheet.get_rows()]

      json_obj = [dict(zip(header, row)) for row in rows]
      return json_obj


if __name__ == '__main__':
  url = ""
  data = ExcelParser.from_url(url)
```